# Java 8 currying Function, unable to determine int[] return-type

Tags: lambda, types, java-8, currying, java-10

Let's say we have a lambda Function like this:

```
Function<ArrayList<Integer>, int[]> func1 = a->new int[2];
```

What it does isn't really important. The important things are: The input is an `ArrayList<Integer>`, and the output is an `int[]`.

Using some basic test compiles and runs without a problem:

```
int[] func1Result1 = func1.apply(new ArrayList<Integer>()); // Non-currying works with <Integer>
System.out.println(func1Result1);
System.out.println(func1Result1.getClass());
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(func1Result1));
System.out.println();

int[] func1Result2 = func1.apply(new ArrayList<>());        // Non-currying works with <>
System.out.println(func1Result2);
System.out.println(func1Result2.getClass());
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(func1Result2));
System.out.println();

int[] func1Result3 = func1.apply(new ArrayList());          // Non-currying works without <>
System.out.println(func1Result3);
System.out.println(func1Result3.getClass());
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(func1Result3));
System.out.println();
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##pZHBasMwDIbvfQrRUzKWlCXHdoUxGAy6HdZj6UFNvNZtYhtbaQmjz57ZSRkdIVlYfYiJ9Eu//GmPRwykYmKfHqqK50pqgr0NhgXxLLybjlqxz0IkxKVwySRDY@ANufgaAahik/EEDCHZ6yh5CrlNeUvSXGxXa0C9Nb5TAixLQywPZUGhslnKhDd@uXSePWmN5YIbmr0KYlum5/dgNav1fOxPu8ptpk5NJrDAfJMiEB6sLyC0@4FCjTkjpgFFCjs0VlZbgGZUaBFQqVjdb8BU4Jg8wCNgMBfsVEejdTNp/Wk616oPZoqMnLj@DVGprPRcVbu/5/tT9553KYKk0Lp0zzlJfTBw4rSDH2EXk2vHbnLXqnDL6Nlt1Xl3FdSTmpBks9nfNn9vqEUj6qXRYLicPhpDMESDMES3Yoj@gyHuw3ANoQ@DdRpGIh5EIr6VRNxPAuA8OlfVNw)

---

Now let's say we have a currying lambda Function like this:

```
Function<Object, Function<Object, int[]>> func2 = a->b->new int[2];
```

Again, what it does isn't important. This time the currying Function takes two `Object` parameters, and still outputs an `int[]`.

Using the same basic tests compiles and runs without a problem again:

```
int[] func2Result1 = func2.apply(new ArrayList<Integer>()).apply(null); // Currying works with <Integer>
System.out.println(func2Result1);
System.out.println(func2Result1.getClass());
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(func2Result1));
System.out.println();

int[] func2Result2 = func2.apply(new ArrayList<>()).apply(null);        // Currying works with <>
System.out.println(func2Result2);
System.out.println(func2Result2.getClass());
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(func2Result2));
System.out.println();

int[] func2Result3 = func2.apply(new ArrayList()).apply(null);          // Currying works without <>
System.out.println(func2Result3);
System.out.println(func2Result3.getClass());
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(func2Result3));
System.out.println();
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##pZPBaoNAEIbvPsWQk5ZqqB5NhRIoFFoKzTHksOrWrFnXZXeMSMmz21XTkpKaSuPBZeef@Wf8BnOyJ24pqcjTXduyQpYKITdBr0LGvZvQOou9VyJBVopOTDjRGl4IEx8WgKxizhLQSNAc@5KlUBjJXqFiIltvgKhMO10mwKrRSAuvrNCTRkUu7Nnj0XnxGuc0wVs4C5jE9SaKZk44ZnJU@td8DstKqcY0dzkp4pQAkp25AdYlDJ4giSIFRao0EJHClphz6AOKYqWEi42kvd/k@aBj5MM9EDeK3UjQulf8TWj1RoN9n/RGdcXxzuT2V49IyRu7q3hQijTPTOPiSSDNqIpsx/nSK86d8PQDoS7VTkPNcAvfBWOQTjuPozzN8jKKy27ZZobRgn5i7WE5LPxnm4sr@52Kf5HKOY7jM0ZlCg5/Eg7/Whz@f3AEl3CMwRjDYTpOIxJMIhJcSyRw/vinD9ahbT8B)

---

Now the third variation, which is where my confusion is and where my question is about. Let's say we have a currying lambda Function like this:

```
Function<ArrayList<Integer>, Function<Object, int[]>> func3 = a->b->new int[2];
```

This time the parameters are an `ArrayList<Integer>` and an `Object`, and the return-type is still an `int[]`.

Using the same basic test this time won't compile, and gives an error:

```
int[] func3Result1 = func3.apply(new ArrayList<Integer>()).apply(null); // Currying works with <Integer>
System.out.println(func3Result1);
System.out.println(func3Result1.getClass());
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(func3Result1));
System.out.println();

int[] func3Result2 = func3.apply(new ArrayList<>()).apply(null);        // Currying works with <>
System.out.println(func3Result2);
System.out.println(func3Result2.getClass());
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(func3Result2));
System.out.println();

int[] func3Result3 = func3.apply(new ArrayList()).apply(null);          // Currying doesn't work without <>
System.out.println(func3Result3);
System.out.println(func3Result3.getClass());
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(func3Result3));
System.out.println();
```

The error is:

> Main.java:23: error: incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to int[]
>    int[] func3Result3 = func3.apply(new ArrayList()).apply(null);          // Currying doesn't work without <>
>                                                                                          ^

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##pZNRa8IwEMff@ykOX2bHWln7qCsMYTDYGMxH8eHaZjWapiW5KmX42V2aOlFcnWgfGnL/u/tff00WuEKvKJlcpMvtludloQgWJuhXxIV/P3ROYl@VTIgXshETgVrDO3L57QCUVSx4ApqQzLIqeAq5kfoTUlxm0xmgyrTbZAJMak0s94uK/NKoJGS/97LrPHpWCus3rmn0KollTEUPsBc/4gVL6AFM0XQWRT132NVwp9jXYADjSqnaDOIJzOMUgXBpdoBwagcoU2iNoESFOSOmtI3O0aytOShGlZIe1SWzJld9ADRAQ3gC9KLYiyRbWyWYDR3btLWySZ9MV4IeTa7d@liWou43FaeGfdf91Ssh3OEhAVgXaqlhzWkO@4IuiofO3awPs/yM0bg5GWaGzgI7sfapaE/Hsc3Zf/o3leAslVMcu6eLyiU4gotwBLfiCK7BEZ7D0QXjGEdaMC3vyGKxVIzxZWDCi8CEt4IJ3X/u/sbZbLc/)

Why does it think the return-type is an `Object` instead of `int[]`? The return-type of the inner Function clearly states the return-type is `int[]`. And it does work correctly if the parameters for both lambdas are `Object` (the `func2` test), or the Collection has diamonds attached (`func3Result1` and `func3Result2`). But for some reason it gets confused when the diamonds are removed from the Collection (`func3Result3`), even though the `int[]` return-type has nothing to do with this `ArrayList<Integer>` input.

EDIT: Just tested it locally on my jdk version 1.8.0_72 and there it does compile and work. Could someone confirm it indeed isn't working on jdk 1.9 or 1.10 (or one of the latest versions of jdk 1.8)? Maybe the problem is TIO doing something weird here instead of the JDK itself.. :S

Comment: [What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2770321/2711488)

Comment: @Holger Thanks for the read. I indeed knew you should never use it, although now I also better understand the reasoning behind it. I'm still a bit confused how Java somehow links the `ArrayList` input-type with the `int[]` return-type in the currying lambda, even though they should have nothing to do with each other. I'm curious if someone could provide the actual JVM code of what's happening in the compiler in these currying lambdas for these particular cases.

Comment: Before Java 8, you could simply say, using a raw type caused an expression to use no Generics at all, so it may not infer types even from entirely unrelated type variables. Well known example, `List list; … String[] array = list.toArray(new String[0]);` doesn’t work due to the use of the raw type `List`, even if `toArray`’s type parameter is unrelated to `List`’s type parameter. Starting with Java 8 and its extended target type inference, rules became much more complicated and it’s not surprising to see differences between compilers (bugs, fixed bugs, specification cleanups).

Comment: From Java9 and up, they've strictened the infer of generic parameters, thats probably why

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In short. When you use raw-types ([you should not use them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it) as mentioned by @Holger in the comments) you erase any generic information. So the line:

```
int[] func3Result3 = func3.apply(new ArrayList()).apply(null);
```

Can be split up into multiple lines for clarification:

```
Function temp = func3.apply(new ArrayList());
```

Here, only `Function` is returned, because the generic information is erased by the use of the raw type `new ArrayList()`.

And a raw type function is somewhat similar, but not equal to `Function<Object, Object>`

Which makes it now quite easy to see that when applying `null` to that function, you don't exactly know what is returned (except that it is an `Object`), and that is why you're getting that Error:

```
int[] func3Result3 = temp.apply(null);
```

The compiler just doesn't know the type, due to type erasure.

So the moral of this is:

> Never use raw types. They are just a backward compatibility feature which should never be used in modern production code.

Comment: Nice answer, +1! As for the main part: "_Here, only `Function` is returned, because the generic information is erased by the use of the raw type `new ArrayList()`._" I'm still a bit confused why. Why is `Function<Object, int[]>` returned when the input would be `new ArrayList<Integer>()` (or `new ArrayList<>()`), but just `Function` is returned when the input is the raw-typed `new ArrayList`? Am I correct in saying that when a raw-typed input is used for a strongly-typed object (`Function<..., ...>` in this case), the output always becomes raw-typed as well?

Comment: @KevinCruijssen That's exactly what is happening. Once a raw type is used. everything else that is using that raw type will lose type information aswell.

Comment: This can best be seen in generic classes which hold objects of other generic types. E.g. `class Box<T>{List<String> strings; List<String> getStrings(){return strings}}` if you dont specify a generic type parameter for `Box`, then `getStrings()` will just return a `List` altough it might seem to not be affected. It still is